# With webpack / source maps / Chrome devtools, stepping into a function call requires several hops

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I'm evaluating webpack for a 10K-line JavaScript app with a bit of [PaperScript](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/).  To test debugging (in Chrome devtools) I configured a tiny test project with source maps (`devtool: 'eval-source-map'`), including a simple custom loader to convert the PaperScript to JavaScript.

Setting a breakpoint in a source file works fine. (So impressive!) But when I step into a function imported from another JS file I land in webpack-generated code, and it takes 3 hops to reach my source code.

Certainly not a dealbreaker, but interestingly when I step into a call to a function imported from a PaperScript file (which uses an identity source map generated by my custom loader) I reach my source code in 1 hop.

Do others experience these multiple hops? Is there something I can configure to eliminate them?

Comment: This is because webpack creates an intermediate function for each export that's used in several places. That extra step is indeed annoying. You can suggest devtools team to implement an automatic skip.

Comment: Thanks - the function in question was only used in one place.

Comment: Then it probably uses something in that module, otherwise it would be inlined, or maybe there's some setting in your webpack config that prevents tree-shaking and inlining. You can inspect the generated code and see what's there.